# Teach Me Step-by-Step on How I can Collaborate and Achieve Reproducibility Using Git and TeXstudio for Latex Documents

Tags: texstudio, windows, git, collaboration

I am using `TeXstudio` with `LaTex` on `Windows` I also know about `Git`. In fact, I use `Git` to collaborate on `RStudio` but on `TeXstudio` I cannot.

1. While typing on `TeXstudio` on my own without collaboration, I had my first problem saving different versions of `.txt` files on the same project, which sometimes confuses me.
2. When I was writing my PhD thesis, I would send the PDF to my professor, which he could not edit.

How do I solve these two problems?

**WHAT I WANT**

I have read different posts on reproducibility on `TeXstudio`, but I cannot figure out my foot on any. I want a step-by-step guide on achieving reproducibility and collaboration on `TeXstudio` using `Git`.

I want to be able to revert to my previous changes without saving multiple documents.

Comment: you are asking multiple questions which are unrelated. for (2) it's not clear what answer you want other than tell your prof to look at the tex source (or use a pdf annotation tool). git and reproducible builds are not related. To git, tex is just a text file so there is nothing really to say: you just edit the files and check them in. Reproducible builds need some settings to set the EPOCH to a fixed time stamp, but do you want that on draft documents? and the settings are the same whether or not you use git

Comment: all the latex sources (and many latex packages) are in git on github look for example at the hyperref manual at https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/tree/main/doc  If we edit that tex document in any editor, just commit changes to git in the normal way using the commandline or a git GUI such as sourcetree or gitkraken or whatever you use. I usually use the commandline and just type `git commit -a -m "changed something" `

Comment: I was trying to tell a story about each of my problems. The most important message is that I need `Git` to work on `TeXstudio`.

Comment: `git` sits behind the scenes, it's not tied to `TeXStudio` or anything else

Comment: @cmhughes Can I connect `Git` with `TeXStudio` and then commit changes all on the `TeXStudio`?

Comment: TeXStudio has some rudimentary git support. If your .tex file is in an existing git repository, you can use the `Check in...` entry in the menu to commit changes (make sure that you selected `use git` in the preferences (I think svn is the default) ) For everything more complicate than committing the current file, like checking out a previous version, I would either use the command line or a dedicated git gui like gitkraken, sourcetree etc.

Comment: but  yuor problems are unrelated. To get bitwise reproducibility on a finished document you need to set the epoch to (any) fixed time so that if you re-run the document it does not get a new internal timestamp so the pdf is identical, but that makes no sense for a document you are editing as if you edit the document it can not make an identical pdf to the previous version.  I don't really see any advantage to doing the git commit from the editor, it may be possible as texstudio allows you to set up menu options for commands I think.